# What is reason to declare not-null field in hibernate Property tag?

Tags: hibernate

What will happen if I declare DB null field as not null in Mapping file? Or if nothing is specified in the Property column but it is a not-null field in the DB? I am confused, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `not-null` attribute is useful when the DB schema is generated by Hibernate; the corresponding DB column will be marked `NOT NULL` in the table. See the documentation for [`<property/>`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property) tag.

> What will happen if i declare DB null feild as not null in Mapping file.

Nothing will happen in this case.

> Or if not specified anything in the Proeprty coulmn but it is an not-null feild in DB?

If your Java code tries to insert an entity with the attribute unspecified, the database (well, at least the good ones) will reject the `INSERT`.